# How to configure Weblogic 12.1.3 to use older version of Jersey while deploying Enterprise App

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic

I have installed Weblogic 12.1.3 as part of upgrade from Weblogic 10.3.6 to Weblogic 12.1.3
My application uses Jersey version 1.17 jars
However, after we install Weblogic 12.1.3, we get Jersey 1.18 Jars inside folder ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules
The Jersey 1.18 Jars override the Jersey 1.17 jars which are bundled in our application and causes error in deploying our application.

### We get error/warning messages as give below

WARNING: Return type javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement of method public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.ipc.dms.dsfs.service.rs.DSFSResource.getEnterpriseContacts(java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.Integer,java.lang.String) is not resolvable to a concrete type

WARNING: Return type javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement of method public javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.ipc.dms.dsfs.service.rs.DSFSResource.getMediaServiceConfigList(java.lang.String) is not resolvable to a concrete type

The application is using ServletContainerInitializer class com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer that is loaded from:file:/opt/oracle/oracle_common/modules/jersey-servlet-1.18.jar. This initializer overrides the one available in the system.
**********>

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jgroups.conf.XmlConfigurator
at org.jgroups.conf.ConfiguratorFactory.getXmlConfigurator(ConfiguratorFactory.java:216)
at org.jgroups.conf.ConfiguratorFactory.getStackConfigurator(ConfiguratorFactory.java:93)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.(JChannel.java:142)

---

If we remove the Jersey 1.18 Jars from ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules we DO NOT get these error messages.

### However, removing jars from installation folder causes other issues.To be specific I get the issue mentioned below if I remove the Jersey 1.18 jars from from ORACLE_HOME/oracle_common/modules

weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1467281457661> < BEA-149231 >  < Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "dunkin".
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)

---

So, I need to know if we can configure our EAR to use older version of Jersey i.e Jersey 1.17 while deploying the application on Weblogic 12.1.3.

If yes, please provide configuration details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have got 2 options:

1. To include the `<prefer-application-packages>` tag in the weblogic-application.xml of your ear as below:

   `<weblogic-application>
       <prefer-application-packages>
          <package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</package-name>
       </prefer-application-packages>
   </weblogic-application>`
2. To inlcude the `<wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>` tag in the weblogic.xml of your war file as below:

   `<wls:container-descriptor>
            <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>true</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
    </wls:container-descriptor>`

If you decide to use option 2 then all the common libs of weblogic will be overidden by the libs of your application. So I would suggest to go with option 1.

Comment: Thank you.. I will try this out